# Repartition dask dataframe while maintaining its original sequence

Tags: dask, parquet, dask-dataframe

I am trying to repartition multiple `.parquet` files in order to save a specific number of parquet files. I have a time-series data that is dependent on the number of observations (instead of timestamps) for each client, so I need to ensure that the partitioning will not split a series over two files. In addition, I want to preserve the order, since I have the labels stored elsewhere. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
ids = [9635, 1536, 8477, 1088, 6411, 2251]

df = df = pd.DataFrame({
            "partition" : [0]*3 + [1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*3 + [4]*3 + [5]*3,
            "customer_id" : [ids[0]]*3 + [ids[1]]*3 + [ids[2]]*3 + [ids[3]]*3 + [ids[4]]*3 + [ids[5]]*3,
            "x": range(18)})
# indexing on "customer_id" here
df = df.set_index("customer_id")
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=6)
ddf.to_parquet("my_parquets")

read_ddf = dd.read_parquet("my_parquets/*.parquet")

last_idx = [ids[-1]]
my_divisions = ids + last_idx

read_ddf.divisions = my_divisions

# Split into two equal partitions with three customers each
new_divisions = [my_divisions[0], my_divisions[3], my_divisions[5]]
new_ddf = read_df.repartition(divisions=new_divisions)
```

which raises an error:

```py
ValueError: New division must be sorted
```

I have tried an alternative approach, which involves setting the "partition" column as the index and modifying the index to "ids" later, but this sorts my entire dataframe, which is undesired because the new sequence no longer matches the labels stored. This is shown here:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
ids = [9635, 1536, 8477, 1088, 6411, 2251]

df = df = pd.DataFrame({
            "partition" : [0]*3 + [1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*3 + [4]*3 + [5]*3,
            "customer_id" : [ids[0]]*3 + [ids[1]]*3 + [ids[2]]*3 + [ids[3]]*3 + [ids[4]]*3 + [ids[5]]*3,
            "x": range(18)})
# indexing on the defined "partition" instead
df = df.set_index("partition")
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=6)
ddf.to_parquet("my_parquets")

read_ddf = dd.read_parquet("my_parquets/*.parquet")

# my_range is equivalent to the list of partitions
my_range = [i for i in range(0,6)]
last_idx = [my_range[-1]]
my_divisions = my_range + last_idx

read_ddf.divisions = my_divisions

new_divisions = [0, 2, 4, 5]

new_ddf = read_ddf.repartition(divisions=new_divisions)

# Need the "customer_id" as index
new_ddf = new_ddf.set_index("customer_id", drop = True)
```

But this sorts the dataframe by the index and messes up the structure, while I would like to keep the original order.

```py
print("Partition 0")
print(new_ddf.get_partition(0).compute())
print("-------------------")

print("Partition 1")
print(new_ddf.get_partition(1).compute())
print("-------------------")

print("Partition 2")
print(new_ddf.get_partition(2).compute())
```

```py
Partition 0
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [x]
Index: []
-------------------
Partition 1
              x
customer_id    
1088          9
1088         10
1088         11
1536          3
1536          4
1536          5
-------------------
Partition 2
              x
customer_id    
2251         15
2251         16
2251         17
6411         12
6411         13
6411         14
8477          6
8477          7
8477          8
9635          0
9635          1
9635          2
```

Are there any workarounds for this issue? I am aware that `set_index` in dask is quite expensive, but none of the approaches are currently working. Also, in my case I already have the `.parquet` files with the preprocessed data, so I only created the initial dataframe using pandas for demonstration purposes (it would have been much easier to specify the number of partitions in the first step if I had all the data in pandas).